# How can I have a code listing appear on the verso page of a new chapter?

Tags: formatting, chapters, double-sided

Using doublepage how can I force a listing, defined immediately after or below a new chapter, appear on the verso page and the new chapter heading and text appear on the corresponding recto page? Thanks!

Comment: do you mean you want them on the same spread with the listing coming first (eg list on page 2 and chapter head page 3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a version of `\cleardoublepage` with odd and even reversed, so that you get on to an even page for the listing, then the chapter heading will naturally come on the other half of the spread.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cleartoevenpage{%
\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
stuff
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\cleartoevenpage
\begin{lstlisting}
int i = 0;
int j = 10;
\end{lstlisting}
\chapter{code}
The code is shown opposite

\section{jjj}
zzzz

\cleartoevenpage
\begin{lstlisting}
int k = 0;
int l = 10;
\end{lstlisting}
\chapter{code more}
More The code is shown opposite



\end{document}
```